# Is there a standard name for a certain parameter for the beta distribution?

Tags: terminology, parameterization

The beta distribution is $$ (\text{constant})\times x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx \quad\text{for } 0\le x\le 1. $$
Supposing $X$ to be so distributed, one has
\begin{align}
& \mu = \operatorname E X = \frac \alpha {\alpha+\beta}, \\[10pt]
& \nu = \operatorname E(1-X) = \frac \beta {\alpha+\beta}, \\[4pt]
& \text{(so that $\mu+\nu=1$)} \\[10pt]
& \operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}(1-X) = \frac{\mu\nu} \kappa \quad \text{where } \kappa = \alpha+\beta + 1.
\end{align}
Thus the family of distributions is parametrized by $(\mu,\kappa)$ or by $(\nu,\kappa).$

I have on occasion called $\kappa$ a “concentration parameter.” Is there some standard name for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard that $\kappa := \alpha+\beta$ is sometimes also referred to as the *precision* of the beta distribution, precisely because if $\mu,\nu$ are fixed, then larger $\kappa$ implies lower variance. The term's meaning should carry over to your definition with the extra $+1$.

Comment: It seems odd to use $\alpha+\beta$ rather than $\alpha+\beta+1,$ since if $\alpha,\beta$ both $\to0$ with the expected value fixed at $1/2$, then the variance approaches $1/4$ but $1/(\alpha+\beta) \to+\infty. \qquad$